# Binding properties from service to component Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a component which I inject a service. I try to bind the properties from the service to the component's html view.

I tried just to bind in a regular way `<p>{{a}}</p>` but it didn't work. I asked here and the answer I got was to refer to the service name first:

service:

```
export class MyService {
    a: string = 'Hello world'; 
    b: number = 1;

    c(): number {
      this.b += 1;
      return this.b;
}
}
```

component.ts:

```
export class myComponent {
constructor(public myService: MyService){}
}
```

component.html:

```
<p>{{myService.a}}</p>
```

I did it and still doesn't work - what do I miss?

If I console the properties in the service methods, then call the method in the component class, it will console the properties. But once I try to bind them in the template - it's doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: create a variable, assign the a property in the constructor, bind this variable to your <p> tag in the html

Comment: Ok, thanks. So you mean that I need to create a variable in the component class and assign to this variable the property from the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You injected the `service` and you are getting value from service. But but but.. you didn't assign it to your `this`.

So just you need to assign your value to this `variable`.

**See below:**

> **myComponent.component.ts**

```
export class myComponent {
  constructor(public myService: MyService){}
  a: any = myService.a;
}
```

Now you can get this `variable` into `HTML`.

> **my.html**

```
<p>{{a}}</p>
```

Comment: Ok!! Thanks thanks thanks. I was assuming that once I inject it it's available. Apparently as you say I need to assign it. Thanks again.

Comment: Pleasure..!! Keep asking..!!